# trasform scale by a percentage of parent size in pure css

Tags: css

I have this

```
.main
 { transform : scale(0.3); }
```

But that is a ratio of the element itself, what I want is something like height:30%
I've been try like this :

```
transform : scale(30%);
```

and

```
transform : scale(calc(30%));
```

But, obviously, that didn't work

Comment: `I want is something like height:30%` --> so use height:30%

Comment: @JoykalInfotech no, it's not a bug. You know the answer or you don't, but no need of a fiddle here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif width and height doesn't do the same things as scale (for exemple it wont change the size of the childs when scale does)

Comment: in this case you need to add more details to your question, actually your question is only talking about having the same as height, you didn't mention any content. Try to always add context and describe precisely your issue if you want accurate answer, don't simply write two words.

Comment: I do add context when the question needs to put context. Here I kept it simple and clear. I never talked about having the same as height, but a transform property that would work "like" height. In addition to the title, I really don't know what to add except confusing stuff. Thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: when you say *I want scale to work like height*, we (readers) we will ask *why you want such thing when you can do it with height? what is the reason? what is the purpose?* ...  for sure you have a requirement and probably you choosed the wrong way to do it. By giving the context and the reason to do this, you make us thing about how to solve your requirement not how to solve the solution you think is the best one to your requirement. You are free to ask the question like you want but you will simply create a limitation for us by not giving enough context for *what you want to achieve*

Comment: This is not possible with CSS (since you want child elements to scale also). **You need javascript**

Comment: I shouldn't have talk about height.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes it is possible, read my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a trick to do that. Simply by creating a super-container. I set it up to 100% of the parent size (in my case, the content is floating out of scope so I can also use a positioning in absolute for a better result)

```css
.v {
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.c {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:scale(.5);
}
```

```html
<div class='c'>
<div class='v'>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Transform is only related to the element itself, it doesn't take parent(s) into account at all so it's not possible with transform in a fully dynamic way.

The only way using transform is using some very fixed (non dynamic values), for example making the child and parent the same size and then using a `transform(.3)` on the child.

https://jsfiddle.net/upgwct7a/

For a more dynamic and flexible way you should use width/height, font-size etc.